# Trying to use a JCheckBox as a JButton (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jcheckbox

i'm trying to get a JDialog to "pop up" when i press a JCheckBox (if its not true). I want to use is as a button. I hope i am posting this right, my first post here :)

I am getting a error that says i can't cast my JCheckBox to a JButton. Can you help me do this right?

package model;

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FirstJDialog extends JDialog 
{
    private Controller controller;

    private HotelJDialog hotelJDialog;
    private PartnerJDialog partnerJDialog;

    private JLabel lblName, lblArrival, lblDeparture, lblLekture, lblHotel, lblPartner;
    private JTextField txfName, txfArrival, txfDeparture;
    private JCheckBox ckbLekture, ckbHotel, ckbPartner;

    public FirstJDialog()
    {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Person informationer");
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(900, 650);
        this.setLocation(500, 200);
        this.setResizable(false);

        // Labels for TextField ######################################################################
        lblName = new JLabel("Navn:");
        this.add(lblName);
        this.lblName.setSize(100, 40);
        this.lblName.setLocation(25, 25);

        lblArrival = new JLabel("Ankomst:");
        this.add(lblArrival);
        this.lblArrival.setSize(100, 40);
        this.lblArrival.setLocation(25, 70);

        lblDeparture = new JLabel("Afgang:");
        this.add(lblDeparture);
        this.lblDeparture.setSize(100, 40);
        this.lblDeparture.setLocation(25, 115);

        // TextField ######################################################################
        txfName = new JTextField();
        this.add(txfName);
        this.txfName.setSize(200, 40);
        this.txfName.setLocation(180, 25);

        txfArrival = new JTextField();
        this.add(txfArrival);
        this.txfArrival.setSize(200, 40);
        this.txfArrival.setLocation(180, 70);

        txfDeparture = new JTextField();
        this.add(txfDeparture);
        this.txfDeparture.setSize(200, 40);
        this.txfDeparture.setLocation(180, 115);

        // CheckBox ######################################################################
        ckbLekture = new JCheckBox();
        this.add(ckbLekture);
        this.ckbLekture.setSize(25, 25);
        this.ckbLekture.setLocation(25, 200);

        ckbHotel = new JCheckBox();
        this.add(ckbHotel);
        this.ckbHotel.setSize(25, 25);
        this.ckbHotel.setLocation(25, 250);

        ckbPartner = new JCheckBox();
        this.add(ckbPartner);
        this.ckbPartner.setSize(25, 25);
        this.ckbPartner.setLocation(25, 300);

        // Labels for CheckBox ######################################################################
        lblLekture = new JLabel("Foredrag");
        this.add(lblLekture);
        this.lblLekture.setSize(100, 40);
        this.lblLekture.setLocation(125, 190);

        lblHotel = new JLabel("Hotel");
        this.add(lblHotel);
        this.lblHotel.setSize(100, 40);
        this.lblHotel.setLocation(125, 240);

        lblPartner = new JLabel("Ledsager");
        this.add(lblPartner);
        this.lblPartner.setSize(100, 40);
        this.lblPartner.setLocation(125, 290);

        // JDialogs ######################################################################
        hotelJDialog = new HotelJDialog();
        partnerJDialog = new PartnerJDialog();

        controller = new Controller();
        ckbHotel.addActionListener(controller);
    }

    private class Controller implements ActionListener
    {                   

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
            JCheckBox sourxe = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
            if(sourxe.equals(ckbHotel))
                hotelJDialog.setVisible(true);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: 1) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556). 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a result of an attempt to cast `JCheckBox` to a `JButton`. This cast is unnecessary, as you never register this listener with any `JButton`, only with `ckbHotel` which is `JCheckBox`.

In the given example, there is no need to cast, you can simply check the source:

```
if(ckbHotel.equals(e.getSource()))
    hotelJDialog.setVisible(true);
```

You can also register a different action listener for this checkbox. There is no need to have a single action listener to serve all the controls in the container, for example:

```
ckbHotel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        hotelJDialog.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
```

this line give this error. remove this ans add this

```
JCheckBox sourxe = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
if(sourxe.isSelected())
      hotelJDialog.setVisible(true);
```

this is only show your dialog if sourxe is selected..